# Facing issues when running a shiny app for Python locally

Tags: python, r, shiny, cmd

I want to run [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) app for [python](/questions/tagged/python) locally. The following code works like a charm:

```
cd/d D:/app1
py
from shiny import run_app
run_app()
```

However, when I try the following code, it does not work.

```
cd/d D:
py
from shiny import run_app
run_app("app1:app")
```

Any hints, please.

I am following the [shiny.run_app documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/py/api/reference/shiny.run_app.html).

Comment: The `CD` command is for changing directories, and `D:` is not a directory, it is a drive. Your first shown line therefore, should be ```CD /D D:\```, where ```\``` is clearly the root directory of the `D:` drive. Your first example at least used a directory location, you were lucky however that the parser automatically replaced your incorrect forward slashes with backward slashes, in order for it to work as intended. Windows file and directory paths, use backward slashes. You were also fortunate, because it does that, you did not have a directory named `d` in one named `cd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further down in the documentation, under examples, it gives the following example:

```py
# Run ``my_app`` inside ``../myapp.py`` (or ``../myapp/app.py``)
run_app("myapp:my_app", app_dir="..")
```

so I'd specify `app_dir="app1"` seeing as your app is in the app1 directory (I think)